# Rest API feed access options

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest, curl

There is a REST API which I want to access and use the GET Method to get the data from xml and store it into MySQL. I thought to give PHP curl a try to request the data from API and setup a cronjob for the script run automatically on the given days. The problem is that the feed is not allowed to be accessed through browser. What other ways are there to get the data and store into mysql?

Comment: That depends on the documentation of the REST API. I guess they wrote down how you can access their system...

Comment: Have you tried using PHP-CLI?

Comment: @inf3rno - the only thing they mentioned was to craft the GET request using fiddler and use it in custom solution. Since I'm new to this, I dont exactly understand. I used fiddler and the request worked fine on it

Comment: @ajtrichards_wales I'm trying to do that at the moment. I've tried to setup a custom user-agent on the curl_setopt and try to execute it using php-cli but it doesn't seem to be working. The response header is HTTP 1.1 200 - OK but the rest api wont pass the data and responds with a custom message - "forbidden", while it works fine if I request it on fiddler.

Comment: Forbidden usually occurs when your credentials are accepted as valid, but you have no permission to perform the operation. But all of this can depend on the implementation and the access control model of the REST API. Without more information I don't think we can help. What exactly you do in fiddler?

Comment: @inf3rno There documentation was seriously flawed and limited and that was the issue. Thanks for all the help though

Comment: I wasn't talking about the documentation, if it is flawed, then use email or telephone...

Answer (score 0):

I used [httpful](http://phphttpclient.com/) client by nate good to solve this issue. Hope it helps other as well.